# PHP Mobile redirect doesn't work

Tags: php, android, redirect, mobile

I have this code where I am trying to redirect mobile users to mobile optimized page and desktop users to desktop page.

```
<?php if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad')||
         stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone')||
         stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod')||
         stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Android')){ ?>

  mobile-page.com

<?php } else { ?>
 dekstop-page.com

<?php } ?>
```

Now I am trying to further redirect mobile Android and Iphone users by doing elseif statement, but I am getting error.

```
 <?php if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad')||
         stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone')||
         stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod')){ ?>

  iphone-page.com

 <?php } elseif(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Android')){ ?>

  android-page.com

<?php } else { ?>
 dekstop-page.com

<?php } ?>
```

Could someone help me where I am doing mistake?

Comment: Use header if you need auto redirection.

Comment: Can you provide the error that you are receiving so that we can better determine the problem you are encountering?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
  if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad')||
             stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone')||
             stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod')||
             stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Android'))
             { 
             header( 'Location: mobilepage.html') ; //forward to mobile page
        } else {
        header( 'Location: desktoppage.html') ;  //forward to desktop page
       }
?>
```

Comment: But I want to redirect Andorid users to andoridpage.com, Iphone users to iphonepage.com and PC user to dekstoppage.com

Comment: change the pagename dude.. Eg: 'Location: blablabla.html'

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$UserInfo = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if (stristr($UserInfo, 'iPad') || stristr($UserInfo, 'iPhone') || stristr($UserInfo, 'iPod')) {
    header('Location: iphone-page.com'); //directs to iphone mobile page                     
} elseif (stristr($UserInfo, 'Android')) {
    header('Location: android-page.com'); //directs to mobile page  
} else {
    header('Location: dekstop-page.com'); //directs to dekstop page
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

@whyceewhite @Subin Thomas @rahul It actually works perfectly fine! I was getting syntax error on my server, because I forgot one curly bracket in my code. This code here is OK. I apologize!

```
I used <?php  else { ?> instead of <?php } else { ?>
```